# How to determine the Public Key Size from the CSR file using Bouncy Castle in java?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, csr

I have a CSR file provided by the client, i'm able to find the key type (RSA/DSA) via **JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest** getPublicKey().getAlgorithm() method, but i'm unable to find any suitable way to determine the length/size of the public key (ex: 1024/2048/4096 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it there isn't any common way to obtain the 'key size' of a public key.  Instead, check your public key to see if it implements interfaces such as [RSAPublicKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) or [DSAPublicKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/DSAPublicKey.html).  If it does, use the various interface methods to extract a property from the key and get the bit length of that, for example:

```
PublicKey publicKey = yourRequest.getPublicKey();
int keySize
if (publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
    keySize = ((RSAPublicKey)publicKey).getPublicExponent().bitLength();
} else if (publicKey instance DSAPublicKey) {
    keySize = ((DSAPublicKey)publicKey).getY().bitLength();
} else {
    // handle other public key types.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke Woodward, it worked fine just a small tweak for getting RSA keySize, it should be 
**keySize = ((RSAPublicKey)publicKey).getModulus().bitLength();**, anyway thanks a lot.